# Setting up CORS in web.config (IIS) for non .NET app

Tags: iis, cors, web-config

I'm trying to allow CORS over a site, using the IIS CORS module (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module), but I'm having troubles.

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
            <add origin="https://my.site" allowCredentials="false" maxAge="120"> 
                <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true"></allowHeaders>
                <allowMethods>
                     <add method="GET" />
                     <add method="POST" />
                     <add method="PUT" />
                </allowMethods>
            </add>
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

with this setup, the OPTIONS (pre-flight) request works fine, but any further request (GET, POST) raise a browser exception because of missing *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*
I tryed to add the following to web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https:/my.site" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

but in this way the OPTIONS fails because there're 2 instances of *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*

Using only custom header the pre-flight fails with code 500 (I think IIS doesn't support OPTIONS method without the CORS module).

IIS CORS module documentation is very poor and googling I only find info related to .NET code, but it's not my case. I can't modify code (and it's not .NET), I need to act on IIS.

How can I make IIS respond properly to CORS requests ?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted, it looks like you have not added your origin correctly.
The origin line should contain a (Fully Qualified Domain Name) [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) or some regex that matches it.

A correct line would look like:

```
<add origin="https://my.site.com" allowCredentials="false" maxAge="120">
```

You can allow subdomains of your domain using:

```
<add origin="https://*.site.com" allowCredentials="false" maxAge="120">
```

From the sounds of it, you aren't receiving the headers you want back from the web server. This may be due to the webserver [Only returning CORS safe headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

Using the [IIS CORS Blog](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module) from Microsoft, I've added in config that will expose the headers back in the request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
            <add origin="https://my.site" allowCredentials="false" maxAge="120"> 
                <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
                    <add header="DNT" />
                    <add header="Host" />
                    <add header="Origin" />
                    <add header="Referrer" />
                    <add header="User-Agent" />
                </allowHeaders>
                <allowMethods>
                     <add method="GET" />
                     <add method="POST" />
                     <add method="PUT" />
                </allowMethods>
                <exposeHeaders>
                    <add header="DNT" />
                    <add header="Host" />
                    <add header="Origin" />
                    <add header="Referrer" />
                    <add header="User-Agent" />
                </exposeHeaders>
            </add>
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, according to [This CORS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-configuration) OPTIONS requests don't get the Allow Headers or Expose Headers configuration applied to them. Hopefully that's not the issue here though.

---

Below I've added the most basic CORS request I can think of. If this request works, then it may be a client side problem you are encountering.

```
fetch('example.com', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: { 'Authorization': authString }
}).then(
    response => response.json()
); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
```

Comment: my.site was only a placeholder. I have the FQDN in the origin. I tryed your second option (without IIS CORS module), but the preflight fails because the custom headers are not added to OPTIONS response. How do you get the custom headers applyed also to OPTIONS ?

Comment: You may have to specify the exact headers you want to allow, since `*` may possibly not be supported in this instance.

Comment: I tryed to use <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, DNT, Host, Origin, Referer, User-Agent, content-type"/>, but still got error 500. I see no Access-Control-* header in the response to OPTIONS. Maybe IIS doesn't manage verb OPTIONS correctrly without CORS module ?

Comment: How are you making these calls? I've never heard of needing headers on the options request. It's just a request from the browser to the web server asking what methods it supports. Are your front end calls to the web server correctly formatted?

Comment: I'm simply doing an Ajax POST. The browser (Firefox, Chrome), does the preflight doing an OPTIONS call and this fails with error 500, unless I enable the IIS CORS module. I've not found a way to force the browser not to do the preflight (I mean programmatically, from javascript, I cannot ask end user to change advanced browser options).

Comment: I've done some additional research... You are right that you need to use the IIS CORS module if the code is not handling the preflight itself, I've never seen IIS used in this way. That was my mistake, sorry about the time wastage. I will update my answer to address only IIS CORS and hope that it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but nothing changed. The preflight goes fine (as before when CORS module enabled), but the effective POST fails because of missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Putting it in <customHeaders>, the preflight fails because of double Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Dog chasing his own tail.... Maybe I've to insert the headers directly in code and not from IIS. But this means modify someone else code and I'd have avoided, for several reasons.